# SOLR stop word: words with 'of' give no results, but when of is excluded we get correct results

Tags: solr, stop-words

Can any one explain how stop words in SOLR work. 
In my `stopword.txt` I have define `of`. In `schema.xml` I have

```
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" 
words="stopwords.txt"enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
```

Now when I search for any thing that contains word `of` does not show up in result.

**Example:** `oil of olay` shows no result, where as `oil olay` shows up correct results.

More of file definition:

```
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/> 
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt"
                    enablePositionIncrements="true"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1"
                    catenateAll="1"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0"
                    types="wdtypes.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.KeywordRepeatFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" updateOffsets="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>

        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="stopwords.txt"
                    enablePositionIncrements="true"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                    generateWordParts="1"
                    generateNumberParts="1"
                    catenateWords="1"
                    catenateNumbers="1"
                    catenateAll="1"
                    preserveOriginal="1"
                    splitOnCaseChange="0"
                    splitOnNumerics="0"
                    types="wdtypes.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
```

When debugging:
+(upclist:cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3AActive&fq=facilitystatus%3AActive&fq=facilityid%3A100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3A%5B0+TO+100%5D&fq=weblifecycle%3A%283+OR+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3A2^1.2 | keywords:cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3aactive&fq=facilitystatus%3aactive&fq=facilityid%3a100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0+to+100%5d&fq=weblifecycle%3a%283+or+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3a2^20.0 | product_elevate:cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3aactive&fq=facilitystatus%3aactive&fq=facilityid%3a100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0+to+100%5d&fq=weblifecycle%3a%283+or+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3a2^5.0 | area:"(cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3aactive&fq=facilitystatus%3aactive&fq=facilityid%3a100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0+to+100%5d&fq=weblifecycle%3a%283+or+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3a2 cream) of wheat qt productresult (row creamofwheatqtproductresultsrow) 10 fq status%3aactive fq facilitystatus%3aactive fq facilityid%3a100 fq inventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0 (to fqstatus%3aactivefqfacilitystatus%3aactivefqfacilityid%3a100fqinventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0to) 100%5d fq weblifecycle%3a%283 (or fqweblifecycle%3a%283or) 4%29 fq (groupnumber%3a2 fqgroupnumber%3a2 creamofwheatqtproductresultsrows10fqstatus%3aactivefqfacilitystatus%3aactivefqfacilityid%3a100fqinventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0to100%5dfqweblifecycle%3a%283or4%29fqgroupnumber%3a2)"~3^2.5 | productid:cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3AActive&fq=facilitystatus%3AActive&fq=facilityid%3A100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3A%5B0+TO+100%5D&fq=weblifecycle%3A%283+OR+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3A2^1.7 | productname:cream+of+wheat&qt=productresults&rows=10&fq=status%3aactive&fq=facilitystatus%3aactive&fq=facilityid%3a100&fq=inventoryctrlcode%3a%5b0+to+100%5d&fq=weblifecycle%3a%283+or+4%29&fq=groupnumber%3a2^10.0)~0.01 ()

Comment: Can you share the whole field definition?

Comment: Yes I can, please see the above, I have added it in the issue description. Thank you for your interest to help.

Comment: Did you test this in the Solr analyze UI?

Comment: What solr version are you using? How have you stored the words in stopwords.txt file like word per line or word in double quotes per line?

Comment: Are you searching on that single field, or using qf= in Dismax, for example, to search on multiple fields?

Comment: Yes I did test on SOLR analyzer and stopwords.txt is one word per line.

Comment: Searching on one single field. Using Edimax.

Comment: Did you test it with only WhitespaceTokenizerFactory + StopFilterFactory? I guess it's on the 'query' analyser, which is somehow not filtering out this stopword.

Comment: You might try setting &debugQuery=true for both searches and checking the debug:{} information, in particular the parsedquery section.

Comment: With WhitespaceTokenizerFactory + StopFilterFactory, WhitespaceTokenizerFactory is being used for a reason.

Comment: Please see above in the issue, added debug trace.

Comment: I was thinking of what debug results you get when you go to http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q=cream+of+wheat&debugQuery=true (and then q=cream+wheat)

Comment: Seeing as you're not removing stopwords on query, you're probably getting the query `oil AND of AND olay`, and `of` can't be found. Try to remove the stopwords on query as well and see if that helps.

Comment: Have you performed a reindex after adding your stop word filter? Also ensure you have the stopwords.txt file in your conf folder.

Comment: Nathan, I'm already doing that. MatsLindh, I agree that on the looking at debug trace I too feel that Stopwords are not removed on query, but if you look at the config file, I'm already doing that. So why we still see 'of' in query.

Comment: @DocSoft Ah, my bad - missed that. You probably want the stopwordsfilter after the lowercasefilter as well, and are you using any value for `qf` as @pihentagyu asked? Otherwise you might be seeing the actual query run against two different fields (the one specified and the default field)

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes I'm using qf

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant, since you say you were searching on only one field (I'm posting it anyway because you say you are using edismax and qf). I had a similar issue when I wanted to boost an exact search, so I made the qf something like this: `<str name="qf">title^45 title_str^55`. The title field was using stopwords and title_str obviously was not. The reason it would often not find the searches using stopwords is described [here](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2013/04/15/querying-more-fields-more-results-stop-wording-and-solrs-mm-min-should-match-argument/). Their solution was to play with the mm values. The solution that worked in my case was to put the title_str in the pf tag (and remove it from the qf tag), so the exact find would come to the top.

Comment: I'm also doing something similar: <str name="qf">
                productname^10 productid^1.7 upclist^1.2 area^2.5 product_elevate^5 keywords^20
            </str>

Answer (score 0):

At last resolved this issue by changing this:

"mm" from 2<-25% To 2<-36%